# Convert nested arrays into HTML structure

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, mapreduce, reduce

I've been thinking over this "simple" exercise for a few days and have gotten really stuck. It's driven me really crazy.
I need to convert nested arrays into HTML. Here is an example of an array:

```js
const data = ['html', [
  ['head', [
    ['title', 'Your title text goes here'],
  ]],
  ['body', { class: 'container' }, [
    ['h1', { class: 'header' }, 'h1 text'],
    ['div', [
      ['span', 'span text2'],
      ['span', 'span text3'],
    ]],
  ]],
]];
```

and the expected result should be like this:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>your title text</title>
  </head>
  <body class="container">
    <h1 class="header">h1 text</h1>
    <div>
      <span>span text2</span>
      <span>span text3</span>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I've started with a helper function (create each tag from an Array), here is how it looks now:

```js
const tagBuilder = (arr) => {
  console.log(arr)
  // ['div']; ==> <div></div>
  if(arr.length === 1) {
    return `<${arr[0]}></${arr[0]}>`
  }
  // Maximum length of the pure array (without nested children) is - 3
  return arr.length === 3
  // ['h1', { class: 'header' }, 'html builder example']
  ? `<${arr[0]} class="${arr[1].class}">${arr[2]}</${arr[0]}>`
  // ['h1', { class: 'header' }]
  : arr.length === 2 && typeof arr[1] === 'object'
  ? `<${arr[0]} class="${arr[1].class}"></${arr[0]}>`
  // ['h1', 'header - text']
  : `<${arr[0]}>${arr[1]}</${arr[0]}>`
}
```

It works fine so far. The tricky part starts when I'm trying to create the actual HTML builder function. I want to iterate through each element of the array, check if it has a nested element (child), save the specified tag, and go deeper.

```js
const buildHTML = (array) => {
  let acc = ""
  const iterator = (arr) => {
    for(const el of arr) {
     
    }
  }
  iterator(array)
  return acc;
}
```

So far I can iterate and save the HTML structure without nested arrays, but it breaks when an Array has children. I was trying "reduce" and nested "map" but no luck. Could you please point me to the solution or to the right way to explore? My guess is that the final function should look like this:

```js
const textAndArrChild = ['div',
['span', 'span text3']];
// <div><span>span text3</span></div>

const tagBuilder = (arr) => {
  // ['div']; ==> <div></div>
  if(arr.length === 1) {
    return `<${arr[0]}></${arr[0]}>`
  }
  // Maximum length of the pure array (without nested children) is - 3
  return arr.length === 3
  // ['h1', { class: 'header' }, 'html builder example']
  ? `<${arr[0]} class="${arr[1].class}">${arr[2]}</${arr[0]}>`
  // ['h1', { class: 'header' }]
  : arr.length === 2 && typeof arr[1] === 'object'
  ? `<${arr[0]} class="${arr[1].class}"></${arr[0]}>`
  // ['h1', 'header - text']
  : `<${arr[0]}>${arr[1]}</${arr[0]}>`
}

const buildHTML = (array) => {
  return array.reduce((acc, el, index, arr) => {
    if(typeof el === 'string' && Array.isArray(arr[index + 1])) {
      acc = tagBuilder([el]);
      // return acc += el.map(buildHTML) // TODO cause error
      // need to iterate through the nested array
    } else {
      // insert pure tags from an array into the acc
    }
    
    return acc;
  }, "")
}



console.log(buildHTML(textAndArrChild))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take our [tour] when you get a chance to get more familiar with our platform and how it works. In the future, please use [snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/11047824) only for *runnable* code, rather than all code in your post. You can put groups of code that isn't runnable in [code blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) rather than snippets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it really much more simple. if we don't consider formatting indents it can looks like this.

```js
const data = ['html', [
  ['head', [
    ['title', 'Your title text goes here'],
  ]],
  ['body', { class: 'container' }, [
    ['h1', { class: 'header' }, 'h1 text'],
    ['div', [
      ['span', 'span text2'],
      ['span', 'span text3'],
    ]],
  ]],
]];

const render = data =>{
  let tag, attributes, childrens;
  
  if(data.length === 2){
    [tag, childrens] = data;
  } else if(data.length === 3){
    [tag, attributes, childrens] = data;
  } 

  let attrStr = ""
  for(let attr in attributes){
    attrStr += " " + attr + '="' + attributes[attr] + '"';
  }
  
  let childrenStr = ""
  if(typeof childrens !== "string"){
      for(let children of childrens){
        childrenStr += render(children);
      }
  } else {
    childrenStr = childrens;
  }
  
  return (`<${tag}${attrStr}>${childrenStr}</${tag}>`)
}

console.log(render(data))
```

Comment: Thank you! This solution really helps me to look at this task from a different angle and do not overcomplicate everything.

Answer (score 2):

⚠️
⚠️⚠️
⚠️⚠️⚠️

Unless this is an exercise **you should never generate HTML in this way! It is a massive security risk**. Consider using a templating library that does encoding/escaping by default such as [mustache](/questions/tagged/mustache).

⚠️⚠️⚠️
⚠️⚠️
⚠️

---

You can make this a little bit easier if you're willing to change the data structure that represents a tag:

```
[tag-name tag-attribute children*]
```

Where a child is either a string or another tag data structure. Example:

```javascript
  ['html', {},
    ['head', {},
      ['title', {}, 'Your title text goes here']],
    ['body', { class: 'container' },
      ['h1', { class: 'header' }, 'h1 text'],
      ['div', {},
        ['span', {}, 'span text2'],
        ['span', {}, 'span text3']]]]
```

We traded an unnecessary wrapper `[]` around the children for a mandatory attribute parameter which is just `{}` if not necessary. Not too bad IMHO.

If we stick with this convention we can declare a `tag` function as such:

```js
const tag = (name, attr, ...children) => {
  // ...
};
```

Because we'll have nested tags the natural solution to generating a full markup is to use recursion:

```js
const tag = (name, attr, ...children) => `
  <${name} ${Object.entries(attr).map(([n, v]) => `${n}="${v}"`).join(' ')}>
    ${children.map(child => typeof child === 'string' ? child : tag(...child)).join("\n")}
  </${name}>
`;

console.log(tag(...markup))
```

```html
<script>
const markup =
  ['html', {},
    ['head', {},
      ['title', {}, 'Your title text goes here']],
    ['body', { class: 'container' },
      ['h1', { class: 'header' }, 'h1 text'],
      ['div', {},
        ['span', {}, 'span text2'],
        ['span', {}, 'span text3']]]];
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I've updated my solution and it works fine. `[<${tag.name}${buildAttrsStr(tag.attributes)}>,${tag.body}${tag.children.map(buildHtml).join('')},</${tag.name}>].join('');` You got the idea. Thanks for the recursion hint ;)